# Powershell: Array vs Hashtable (or both) not sure how to proceed

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, hashtable

I have the following powershell script:

```
$grouped_TPR_Test1=Import-Csv c:\TPR.csv | group UPC -AsHashTable -AsString
Import-Csv c:\HQ.csv  | foreach{
$tpr_Sales=($grouped_TPR_Test1."$($_.UPC)" | foreach {$_.TPR_Sales}) -join ","
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TPR_SALES -Value $tpr_Sales -PassThru 
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\HQ_TPR_sales.csv
```

It finds/matches the UPC value in file c:\TPR.csv  with the same value in this file.   c:\HQ.csv and outputs the corresponding sales data from to a 3rd file that includes all fields in c:\HQ.csv as well as the additional ones that match on UPC from c:\TPR.csv

This works.

However, I am not sure how to add a second field to check (**"Zone"**, to narrow down the results that are sent to the 3rd output file. Both files have the zone field as well.

I read a bit on this and an array seems better suited for multiple criteria, rather than a hashtable, but I'm not having much luck.

```
c:\HQ.csv looks essentially like this:                                    

UPC           ZONE column1  column2  column3
1234567890123   3    blah1  blah2    blah3

c:\TPR.csv looks essentially like this:

UPC            ZONE sales
1234567890123   3   5.00
1234567890123   2   4.00
3210987654321   2   3.00
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this  a script file, or are you purposely trying to cram everything into a single line? If it's a script file, then I'd suggest not trying to pipe everything.

Comment: The result is not a script, but another (3rd) .csv file I am purposely trying to cram everything into for each specific UPC / (and now additionally, Zone) combination into a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just use WHERE-OBJECT on the resulting file to just pull out the zone(s) you are interested in:

```
Import-CSV c:\HQ_TPR_sales.csv | WHERE-OBJECT {$_.Zone -eq 2}
```

Or put the WHERE-OBJECT into your pipe before you export-csv:

```
... | ? {$_.Zone -eq 2} | Export-CSV ...
```

Comment: That's a good idea, and I would if my zones were limited to a few, but unfortunately there are many zones and many UPCs.  My example above is for simplicity,  sorry, I should have mentioned that.